# Why is a partion entry 16 bytes in length in MBR?

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader, mbr

According to [this website](http://www.ntfs.com/partition-table.htm), the MBR boot record, each partition entry out of the four is of 16 bytes in length. Why is it so?

> “The information about primary partitions and an extended partition is contained in the Partition Table, a 64-byte data structure located in the same sector as the Master Boot Record (cylinder 0, head 0, sector 1). The Partition Table conforms to a standard layout that is independent of the operating system. Each Partition Table entry is 16 bytes long, making a maximum of four entries available.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Each partition entry out of the four is of 16 bytes in length. Why is it so?

Because the format of a [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (first introduced in 1983 with PC DOS 2.0) has become a de-facto standard so that newer version of operating systems can read disks that were formatted and created with older versions. In other words it hasn't been changed in order to allow backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.